# Permission denied for Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have firebase database rules set up like this

```
"Users":{
        
         "$user_id":{

            "Name":{
                    ".read":"auth != null",
                    ".write":"auth.uid == $user_id"
                },

            "Email":{
                    ".read":"auth != null",
                    ".write":"auth.uid == $user_id"
                },

            "Address":{
                    ".read":"auth != null",
                    ".write":"auth.uid == $user_id"
                },

            "Photo":{
                    ".read":"auth != null",
                    ".write":"auth.uid == $user_id"
                },

            "Number":{
                    ".read":"auth.uid == $user_id",
                    ".write":"auth.uid == $user_id"
                }
,
            "Current":{
                    ".read":"auth != null",
                    ".write":"auth.uid == $user_id"
            }
         }

       }
```

The code that makes the request

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseConstants.USERS).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null)
{
    Log.i("DetailsActivity","User id "+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

}
else
{
    Log.i("DetailsActivity","User not authenticated");
}
                       
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(FirebaseConstants.NAME))
                {
                    Name = dataSnapshot.child(FirebaseConstants.NAME).getValue().toString();
                    UserNameEdittext.append(Name);

                }
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(FirebaseConstants.EMAIL))
                {
                    Email = dataSnapshot.child(FirebaseConstants.EMAIL).getValue().toString();
                    UserEmailEdittext.append(Email);
                }
                userInfoProgressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                userInfoProgressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.i("DetailsActivity","error "+databaseError);

            }
            
});
```

Logged Results

```
I/DetailsActivity: User id KfiIFOEGWQZIc5UREqX8qo4Nmkn1
I/DetailsActivity: error DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

When an **authenticated** user is making a request to the $user_id node under users node, it results in **Permission Denied** error. Firebase database rules works atomically, but all the read permissions are checking whether he is an authenticated user or the user is accessing his own data. When the user reads his own data and all read conditions are satisfied but still getting **Permission Denied** error.

But when I try to read any of these fields individually there is no errors

```
userRef.child(FirebaseConstants.NAME).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    Name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.i("DetailsActivity","Name "+Name);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                userInfoProgressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.i("DetailsActivity","error "+databaseError);

            }        
});
```

I get the log as

```
I/DetailsActivity: Name elsonjose
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that performs the query. Also illustrate in that example that you are certain that a user is signed in at the time of the query.

Comment: try with these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942493/android-firebase-database-error-permission-denied/50450701#:~:text=Go%20to%20firebase%20console%20and,write%20operations%20on%20your%20database.&text=Go%20to%20the%20Rules%20tab,then%20permission%20will%20be%20denied. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424544/firebase-database-permission-denied-with-read-write-permissions-set-to-true

Comment: @Sadegh Tried refreshing google-services.json, no luck there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a default set to:

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
```

You do have rules for single fields, but you are likely getting "Permission denied" when reading the whole user record because you don't have any rules set for the `"$user_id"` path itself. Try adding:

```
    "Users": {
          "$user_id": {
            // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id"
          } 
...
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I wanted to allow certain users to access only particular data. After going through the documentation I found out that we cant really use firebase rules for filtering users.
For filtering users some of the links that I found useful are
[https://www.toptal.com/firebase/role-based-firebase-authentication]
[https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e#:~:text=Most%20applications%20need%20to%20implement,to%20implement%20such%20a%20system.]

Comment: If you want to have user roles and rules around them, you can create a "profiles" collection in the database where you store user properties. That's the only way I know to achieve the functionality purely with firebase tools.