# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) even when I'm not trying to open any file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I had app where you can read books from pdf url, fnd it worked well but book loads everytime i open book read page, then i wanted to save pdf first time i open page, and i was watching some tutorial for it, and first thing i did was that i declared this line in Manifest "

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

"

Then without writing any code i launched app but the books did not load as if there was no internet connection, but there was! So then i deleted that Write External Storage stroke and issue did not gone, from there i can't load books as i did usual.

SOLUTION: The solution was simple, and it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953004/19915097

Also good explanation of how loading data from firebase database works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47853774/19915097

Comment: "Не удалось загрузить данные с сервера("

Comment: Your error is coming from Glide. You will need to examine where you are using Glide in your project.

Comment: Presumably you are failing at `load(book.imageUrl)`. Perhaps the server is returning a 404 for that request.

Comment: book.imageUrl.equals("Не удалось загрузить данные с сервера(" ). Second time i tell you. Put a real url in it.

Comment: @blackapps yeah, i got you, thanks. To get value from database i'm using reference.addListenerForSingleValuesEvent and somewhy onDataChangeListener doesn;t invoke

Comment: whare is save you your pdf file in device storage?

Comment: @UrvishShiroya No, it's saved in firebase storage and the url to it saved in firebase realtime database

Comment: @UrvishShiroya And i read pdf from url using PdfViewer library. Here is link: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: can you provide more log?